# Probability of picking out two heads in a bag of four coins?

Tags: probability

All fair coins.

You pick 2 out of the bag and look at them, they are all heads.

So what is the probability of it?

I made a table under but it does not seem to work.

```
A = Coin #1, B = Coin #2, C = Coin #3, D = Coin #4.

        A   B   C   D
    1   H   H   H   H        >>> AB, BC, CD, DA = 4 chances of head?
    2   H   H   H   T        >>> AB, BC, CA = 3 chances of head?
    3   H   H   T   H        >>> AB, BD, DA = 3 chances of head?
    4   H   H   T   T        >>> AB = 1 chance of head?
    5   H   T   H   H        >>> AC, CD, DA = 3 chances of head?
    6   H   T   H   T        >>> AC = 1 chance of head?
    7   H   T   T   H        >>> DA = 1 chance of head?
    8   H   T   T   T
    9   T   H   H   H        >>> BC, CD, DB = 3 chances of head?
    10  T   H   H   T        >>> BC = 1 chance of head?
    11  T   H   T   H        >>> BD = 4 chance of head?
    12  T   H   T   T
    13  T   T   H   H        >>> CD = 1 chance of head?
    14  T   T   H   T
    15  T   T   T   H
    16  T   T   T   T
... and so on?
```

This problem I created myself but I don't know if I created it right or not. Please help me solve this, thank you!

Comment: Inside the bag, the coins may be heads up or heads down. So, it does not matter how you wind up with two coins. It does not change the probability that you have two fair coins, each with equal chance of showing heads or tails. You have not added any conditions that would change the probability. Each coin has a 50% chance of being heads, so the total probability of both heads is 25%.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe, I struggled with it the whole day and you made it clear in just a minute, thank you so much for such a detail answer, I really appreciate you!

Comment: @InterstellarProbe: Why such long comments instead of an answer? There's not much to say beyond this, so if you don't post that as an answer, the question will likely remain unanswered and clog the system.

Comment: @joriki Fair point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are six possible combinations of coins:
$$AB,AC,AD,BC,BD,CD$$

For each row, you need to check if both of them are heads or not. It breaks down to this:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}\text{Row} & \text{Number Pairs With Two Heads} \\ \hline 1 & 6 \\ 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 3 \\ 4 & 1 \\ 5 & 3 \\ 6 & 1 \\ 7 & 1 \\ 8 & 0 \\ 9 & 3 \\ 10 & 1 \\ 11 & 1 \\ 12 & 0 \\ 13 & 1 \\ 14 & 0 \\ 15 & 0 \\ 16 & 0\end{array}$$

Each row has $\dfrac{1}{16}$ chance of being the actual row, and independently, there is an $\dfrac{x}{6}$ chance that you wind up with a pair of heads (where $x$ is the number of pairs out of six for that row). You can just add up all of the $x$'s, which add to 24.

$$\dfrac{1}{16}\cdot \dfrac{24}{6} = \dfrac{1}{4}$$